# Flutter: Firebase Firestore giving "No object exists at the desired reference." on delete

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete a file like so:

```
Reference s =_storage.ref("some full url");

print(s.fullPath);

//delete from storage
s.delete();
```

But I wlaways get:

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference. #0      MethodChannelReference.delete (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:35:7)

It worked previously, but I recently updated firebase storage to 8.0.4. When I print the full path of the reference I get the URL link that opens up to the photo. Flutter doctor checks out. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ref` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/ref.html) takes an argument described as:

> [String? path]

So it sounds like that need to be the relative path to the file inside the storage bucket.

From what you describe you have a so-called download URL, which you need to pass to  [`refFromURL`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/refFromURL.html) instead.

So:

```
Reference s =_storage.refFromURL("some full url");
```

Comment: I tried this as well. Still does not work.